# How is potential energy lost when a water droplet is dropping down slowly on a wall?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, friction, potential-energy, dissipation

When a water droplet is on a vertical wall, it usually drops slowly, which is different from free falling. As the dropping speed is slower than free drawing, so I guess some energy must be lost.

I guess it is lost as internal energy, but if it is true, how a water droplet gains internal energy when dropping slowly in microscope view?

Comment: I think this is an interesting system to investigate and also can be a lot of fun. I feel like one needs to consider the fact that as the droplet slides it leaves a layer of water behind, that is, a trace. I guess depending on the material of the wall one can make a guess for the thickness of the water layer left behind. This would cause the mass of the droplet decrease as the droplet slides, that is, mass is function of the height. I also feel like the viscosity of water somehow should enter the consideration. That is to say a droplet of oil would slide at different speed than water.

Comment: Depends on how we model the process. If the droplet remains almost spherical, leaving no trail behind, the answer would be mostly friction. On the other hand, if the droplet leaves a trail of water behind, things gets complicated because the extension of the water-air interface is not constant and this means that we have to take interface energy into account.

Answer (score 1):

You are not dealing with dry friction here.  What is involved is viscous flow within the water droplet.  There is a viscous circulation pattern set up within the water droplet, and the flow results in viscous dissipation of the (mechanical) potential energy to internal energy. So, if the water droplet where somehow insulated from its surroundings thermally, its temperature would rise (a tiny amount).  In reality, the thermal energy is transferred to the surroundings.

Comment: I would assert that viscosity is a type of friction.

Comment: You can assert whatever you want.  It's just a mater of terminology.  As a fluid mechanics guy, however, I would never interpret viscosity as a type of friction.  The fundamental physical mechanism leading to dry friction is completely different from that leading to viscous forces.

Comment: Fair enough my friend, I did not mean to put you on the defensive. Let me expand on my point: The energy loss due to friction and the energy loss due to viscous flow both come from the random nature of the interactions. I can certainly understand that specialists have their own terminology here, but in speaking to a non-specialist who wants to understand the underlying idea... I am not sure what benefit there is separating the two concepts unless we expand on how they are different. Rather, I do see benefit in building upon a concept with which they have some familiarity. All the best!

Answer (score 0):

The energy loss is frictive in nature. As the drop slides down the surface, there is a complex interaction at the interface between the droplet and the wall. This will go into changing the temperature of the water droplet, kicking some molecules off, etc...

Perhaps someone with a litter better skills in thermodynamics could help here, but I think you should be able to estimate the temperature change in the water droplet if you know its velocity as a function of time down the wall. The work done by friction should have some relationship to the amount of heat transferred into the droplet. My gut says those two are equal, but I am having trouble justifying that answer. Obviously in vacuum, there should be no heating.

Answer (score 0):

Energy lost because it create a layer of water as it slides down, and layer created due to the viscous force between the liquid - liquid layer and liquid - container layer. 
What happens is the fluid experience, s a Shear force as it slides (tangential) , and this Shear force is cause of energy. Loss, as Water flows down drop become small and energy lost will continue till the size of drop become negligible.